# javascript error in micro soft edge console

Tags: javascript, html, css, microsoft-edge

Microsoft edge show this error when ever I use a style.etc line

```
{"notifyType":"consoleItemLog","message":{"message":"","styles":"","hasFormatString":true,"fileUrl":"file:///C:/Users/wed/Documents/newVogel/js/Myscript.js","lineNumber":8,"columnNumber":9}}
```

I have tried almost all the elements and used `getelementbyclassname` and `elementbyid`, also not solved

```
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("top_header_area")[0].style.height);
```

and when I use `getattribute` it returns null.

Comment: How about posting your actual code.

Comment: Are you certain that the element you're targeting with `getElementsByClassName()` exists on the webpage at the moment your javascript runs? Can you post some sample HTML/javascript that reproduces the issue?

Comment: var banner = document.getElementById("fixed_section");
        console.log(banner.getAttribute("height"));

Comment: <!-- Top Header_Area -->
        <div class="top_header_area" id="fixed_section"></div>
        <!-- End Top Header_Area -->

Comment: Edit the question instead of putting arbitrary code fragments into comments. The questions is very low quality as it stands right now.

Answer (score 0):

How do you apply the style `height`? `getAttribute` and `style` can only get the inline style. If you want to get the internal style sheet, you should use `getComputedStyle`. You could check my sample codes to see the difference.

**Inline style:**

```js
var banner = document.getElementById("fixed_section");
console.log(banner.getAttribute("style"));
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("top_header_area")[0].style.height);
```

```html
<div class="top_header_area" id="fixed_section" style="height:100px"></div>
```

**Internal style sheet:**

```js
var banner = document.getElementById("fixed_section");
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(banner, null).height);
```

```css
#fixed_section{
    height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top_header_area" id="fixed_section"></div>
```